# Seeking ambient screen recorder

Tags: applications, screen-capture

I am a work-from-home developer that gets paid by the hour.

I am seeking an app that runs in the background and records my screen(s) and uploads it (every 20 seconds or so) through FTP to my webserver.

That way, I can set up a simple website for my clients, and they can "watch me work" and be assured that I am really working for them, and not just goofing around or playing games.

It will have to be a ambient app, meaning that it should be very discreete and not interfere in my work (xcode/unity stuff mainly)

Im willing to pay a fair shareware fee, but not anything subscription-based.

Comment: I've generally solved or prevented this kind of trust issue by working at their site at the beginning of a job, and a few days in, promising a piece of work that I'll do in my own office and deliver on [specified day].  Then I show up on that day with it done.  They usually relieved to find out they don't need to baby-sit me and they seldom care where or when I work after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Automator to build a workflow to do this.  Automator can take screenshots and you need to use a shell script to upload the screenshot unless you have an FTP client which is compatible with Automator.  Bear in mind that uploading a screenshot might take longer than 20 seconds depending on screen size and your internet connection speed.  A 5-minute interval might be more appropriate.

Here is an Automator workflow which I just tested successfully to take a screenshot and upload it to an ftp server.

NB: you need to set the shell script step to ignore input from the previous step or it will fail when trying to convert the image to text.
[image: Automator Workflow]
You can save this workflow as a .workflow file and then you need to schedule it to run on whatever interval you think is appropriate.  You could do this through iCal but I think iCal would only allow you to run it daily or less frequently.  So you need something else.  You could do it by writing a `launchd` script or you could use a utility like [lingon](http://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/lingon/id411211026?mt=12) to create the script for you.  This way you could set it to run on whatever interval you like.

Comment: Great chaining of tools - just be sure to unload the launchd job before sleeping. Launchd will detect jobs that  should have run and could perhaps schedule a few more snaps than you want. A quick test to track the last pass and this pass would prevent dumping stale or too many snaps if launchd schedules them too rapidly.

Comment: Wow, this was right on the money. I will try making a script with this right away. +1 and approved.

Comment: Hope it works for you then, the only hurdle is getting it to run every x seconds/minutes so if you find launchd a bit complex then that app 'lingon' might make it simpler

Answer (score 1):

`/3/ftp_screenshots.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmp=${TMPDIR}`uuidgen`.png
screencapture $tmp
fn=`date '+%m-%d-%H-%M'`.png
ftp -in ftp.server.tld<<FTP
user username pa55word
binary
cd www
put $tmp $fn
bye
FTP
rm $tmp
```

I'd prefer SSH ([ssh - Upload file with SCP bash script - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063481/upload-file-with-scp-bash-script)), but I still haven't figured out how to set up SSH keys.

---

`~/Library/Preferences/ftp_screenshots.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>ftp_screenshots</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>/3/ftp_screenshots.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1800</integer>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

These functions could be helpful:

```
laload() { launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/"$1".plist; }
launload() { launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/"$1".plist; }
```

Comment: Cool! +1 for you